# Can't get Wix custom action to work in Votive/VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, votive

Help! I need to execute a managed custom action in my Wix 3.5 setup project and no matter what I've tried I can't get it to work.

I'm using the Votive integration in Visual Studio 2010. My Wix Product.wxs file is basically unchanged from the visual studio template except a few text changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="666ffc07-90b2-4608-a9f0-a0cc879f2ad0" Name="Product Name" Language="1033" Version="5.5.0002" Manufacturer="TiGra Astronomy" UpgradeCode="d17a5991-b404-4095-9e93-08d2db984cfd">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Directory Name">
                <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
                <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="3ea5ade7-9b7b-40da-9e83-13e066a000ef"> -->
                    <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
                <!-- </Component> -->
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ASCOM Driver" Level="1">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this ComponentRef element and the Component above in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" /> -->

        <!-- Note: The following ComponentGroupRef is required to pull in generated authoring from project references. -->
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

I have set a reference to my managed custom action project, set the HARVEST property to true. The project is called `WIX.CustomActions` and produces `WIX.CustomActions.dll` and `WIX.CustomActions.CA.dll`

I see that Wix is processing the reference during build and the `WIX.CustomActions.dll` assembly shows up in the Binary table in the final setup project, but the `WIX.CustomActions.CA.dll` does not.

I have a `CustomActions.wxs` that should package and invoke the custom action:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <Binary Id="DriverRegistrationCA" SourceFile="$(var.WIX.CustomActions.TargetDir)\$(var.WIX.CustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="RegisterDriver" BinaryKey="DriverRegistrationCA" DllEntry="RegisterAscomDriver" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterDriver" BinaryKey="DriverRegistrationCA" DllEntry="UnregisterAscomDriver" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RegisterDriver" After="InstallFinalize" />
      <Custom Action="UnregisterDriver" Before="RemoveFiles" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I've looked at various 'howto' sources on the interweb and they are at best confusing, with contradictory advice. As I understand it, the `WIX.CustomActions.CA.dll` file is an unmanaged dll that loads the .NET framework and passes control to the 'real' managed custom action. However, the `WIX.CustomActions.CA.dll` does not get packaged in my MSI file. I've followed examples as best I can but I can't see what's wrong.

Please, has anyone got this working in Votive? Can you give me an actual working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a reference (e.g., CustomActionRef) from your product to the fragment; otherwise, it's discarded by the smart linker.

Comment: Doesn't Votive do that via the `<ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
` line? If not, then could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: definitelt good advice. I added a couple of CustomActionRef lines near the top of my Product.wxs and now the CA shows up in the MSI file.Bob, you are a superstar. Why oh why do none of the examples mention that step?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Bob Arnson's suggestion, I added the following two lines near the top of my Product.wxs file:

```
<CustomActionRef Id="RegisterDriver"/>
<CustomActionRef Id="UnregisterDriver"/>
```

That seems to have done the trick. Orca now shows that I have a Binary table, containing my CA dll, and a CustomAction entry in InstallExecuteSequence.

None of the examples I found on the web mentioned this requirement. I guess people were just recycling received wisdom with little or no understanding. So here is the answer, thanks to Bob!

Comment: You only need references when the authoring you want is in a different fragment. And you only need one -- the linker will pull in the entire fragment when it finds one reference. And that's recursive, so if authoring in that fragment has a reference to an id in a different fragment, that fragment will get pulled in too. (For example, CustomAction/@BinaryKey is a reference to a Binary/@Id.)